# No intent from UserRecoverableAuthIOException using Drive SDK for Android

Tags: java, android, exception, google-drive-api

I've implemented google drive into my android application and it work pretty nice, but I'm trying to figure out a way to run an upload/download in a background thread so that I can leave an activity and do something else on my app. The problem is, drive needs the activity reference in case of exceptions, such as `UserRecoverableAuthIOException`.

Here's the issue I cannot understand. Here's some try/catch code:

```
try {
    //...drive api stuff here
} catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
    possibleException = e;
    try {
        e.getIntent();
    } catch ( NullPointerException e2 ) {  //this is the crazy part
        // e.getIntent() should not throw a nullpointer
        e2.printStackTrace();
        possibleException = e2;
    }
    onActivityRestartWhat = RESTART_IMPORT;
    // just a note i do handle this exception properly in another section of a code when there is an intent.
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    possibleException = e;
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    possibleException = e;
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What I can't figure out is why `UserRecoverableAuthIOException` is throwing a `NullPointerException` whey I try to access `getIntent`.

#### More Info

I do catch `UserRecoverableAuthIOException` when more authentication is needed and request it via the `startActivityForResult` method. Also, this exception is thrown only if I back out of the activity that has started, aka destroy the activity. Basically, I have a process that uploads/downloads drive files in a thread and if I don't leave the activity until completion it works, if I destroy the activity via the back button then I get this exception.

#### Stack Trace

```
07-10 14:45:32.903: W/System.err(1450): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-10 14:45:32.913: W/System.err(1450):     at android.content.Intent.<init>      (Intent.java:3529)
07-10 14:45:32.913: W/System.err(1450):     at    com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException.getIntent(Unknown Source)
07-10 14:45:32.913: W/System.err(1450):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException.getIntent(UserRecoverableAuthIOException.java:62)
07-10 14:45:32.913: W/System.err(1450):     at my.app.DriveHelper$2.run(DriveHelper.java:211)
```

#### My Desire

I want to run downloads/uploads (via google drive) in a background thread. Since the sdk requires `startActivityForResult` and other methods that might require a reference to an `Activity` or `Context` that makes this difficult, but it should work once the app has been granted the sdk permissions that require those references. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Could you send a stack trace?

Comment: @BurcuDogan I added a stack trace. Note I'm catching the NullPointerException thrown when `getIntent()` runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are the steps you can follow to handle `UserRecoverableAuthIOException` Exception properly and you can even avoid getting that exception when back pressed.

In some cases if you are receiving that error mean the activity is destroyed so you shouldn't depend on the activity

- You need to
  create fresh `com.google.api.services.tasks.Tasks` object from
  `Context` of `Service` not from any `Activity` directly like shown in 'tasks-android-sample'

When you get Exception

1. You need show a notification with `PendingIntent` from `Service`
2. `PendingIntent` should contain the reference to an Activity , say
   HomeActivity
3. Activity should handle the intent extra and should do
   the required things like showing choose account dialog

you can go through the sample code [here](https://github.com/xisberto/phonetodesktop/blob/c502286cb275d0a7c1808b2fcce3d198103bae4a/src/net/xisberto/phonetodesktop/GoogleTasksService.java) (GoogleTasksService)

Comment: Looks like a sensible answer. Thanks for sharing! I thought about using a service, but wandered how I could "connect" to an activity from it to run `startActivityForResult`. I'm going to work on implementing it and then mark it as the correct answer once I get it working.

Comment: Finally got to implementing this. Your solution is good, I handled a few things differently but the overall concept is the same. This works good for having a service run things in the background when needing user interacting infrequently. Ex:
* download file from drive
* start service
* get google drive service
* drive service needs user to pick an account
* launch notification that has a PendingIntent to an activity to handle this

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, in this case don't use multiple activities.

By switching to views you can achieve your task.